# Sequelize migration fails with unique constraint error using sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize migration which ran fine until I switched from sequelize version 5.21.13 to 5.22.3 (same result with version 6.2.4) using sqlite3. Due to the limited ALTER TABLE support in Sqlite my call to queryInterface.removeColumn() will internally create a backup table, copy all the data into it, create the new table without the column and copies everything back into it. This solution by the sqlite team is very drastic but it worked. Now using sequelize version 5.22.3 the automagically created backup table does have columns with unique constraints which have not been in the original table. While copying the data in the backup table, these unique constraints cause the error. Anyone has experienced the problem yet and solved it?